# why is rails3 so stupid about creating huge load paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've been frustrated with the ~30 second rails environment start up time in production, so been tracing it some, and it seems a huge part of it is the load path craziness.

Here's a log including 3 files - for some reason they're loaded differently in each case.  Why do the top ones check each subdirectory first before the final directory?  Any suggestions on optimizations to make to improve this?

```
lstat64("/data", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/parsers", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/data/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/parsers/content_disposition.rb", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12151, ...}) = 0


lstat64("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=17588, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so", O_RDONLY) = 10
read(10, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\260\4\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(10, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=17588, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 10692, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 10, 0) = 0x589000
mmap2(0x58b000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 10, 0x1) = 0x58b000
close(10)                               = 0
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/vendor/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/app/assets/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/app/controllers/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/app/helpers/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/app/models/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/vendor/plugins/country_select/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.2.0/vendor/gems/metric_parser-0.1.0.pre1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/yui-compressor-0.9.6/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/will_paginate-3.0.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/utility_belt-1.1.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory);
...
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.2.9/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-source-1.1.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/cocaine-0.2.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/big_sitemap-1.0.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-3.11/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@newap/gems/bundler-1.0.17/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/xml-simple-1.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/awesome_print-0.4.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/addressable-2.2.6/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/acts_as_taggable_redux-19a19d2d5775/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/open4-1.2.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/Platform-0.4.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@newap/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.2.0/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/vendor/regin/enc/trans/single_byte.rb", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/vendor/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/app/assets/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/app/controllers/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/app/helpers/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/app/models/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/data/u/apps/newap/releases/20111108044231/vendor/plugins/country_select/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.2.0/vendor/gems/metric_parser-0.1.0.pre1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/yui-compressor-0.9.6/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/will_paginate-3.0.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/utility_belt-1.1.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-1.0.4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.0.rc4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-1.3.0.rc4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/slim-1.0.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/temple-0.3.4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.1.4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.10/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sanitize-2.0.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ruby-prof-0.10.8/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-dd82d6caf24e/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pr_geohash-1.0.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/payment-1.0.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/parallel_tests-0.6.7/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/parallel-0.5.9/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.4.5/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/oink-0.9.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.2.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/ext/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/koala-1.2.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kgio-2.6.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/irb_hacks-0.2.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/hodel_3000_compliant_logger-0.1.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/hirb-0.5.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.1.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flyrb-1.0.0.c/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wirble-0.1.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/multipart-post-1.1.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ezcrypto-0.7.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/escape-0.0.4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-1.1.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/crewait-0.1.7/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/creditcard-1.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/cranky-0.3.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.2.9/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-source-1.1.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/cocaine-0.2.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/big_sitemap-1.0.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-3.11/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@newap/gems/bundler-1.0.17/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/xml-simple-1.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/awesome_print-0.4.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/addressable-2.2.6/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/acts_as_taggable_redux-19a19d2d5775/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-0.3.30/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.2.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemerchant-1.18.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/money-3.7.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.1/ext/json/ext/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.1/ext/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/braintree-2.12.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/active_utils-1.0.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.10/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mime-types-1.17.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/hike-1.2.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.0.3/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/POpen4-0.1.4/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/open4-1.2.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/Platform-0.4.0/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@newap/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 10
```

Comment: just to reply with the additional work I did on this, looks like instead of just smart-guessing the dir for each loaded module, it adds it to the load path.  Like treetop needs /u/apps/newap/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.10/lib/treetop.rb - so to 'require' it, that directory needs to be added to the load path.  But it should be possible to hack in trying to require the file "guess" based on that module, and avoid adding it to the load path if it could be found in the expected .../lib/module_name.rb location, thus speeding up things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3.2 improves this some.  The real answer is to ignore small performance things like this and be patient :)

Comment: That doesn't really explain WHY the rails developers thought this was a good idea in the first place, which I think is OP's question.